# Events and Virtual methods in System.Web.UI.Page class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am able to hook the event and also allowed to override load and init.., events in my aspx codebehind file. I have following questions.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Default()
    {
        this.Init += Default_Init;
        this.Load+=Default_Load;
    }    
    protected void Default_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        }    
    protected void Default_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        }    
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {        }
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {        }
}
```

Qs:

1. Why such option(both virtual method and event handler) is exist in Page class?
2. When override methods got executed, my event handlers(Default_Load and Default_Init) are not executed. what is the reason behind?
3. Should i call base.OnLoad(e); in overridden OnLoad method? Why should/shouldn't I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By default, `OnInit` and `OnLoad` are not handlers of `Init` and `Load` events. They are used to Fire `Init` and `Load` events.
2. When you override, you change the behavior of these methods thus, events are not fired by `OnInit` and `OnLoad` methods (unless you explicitly write `base.OnInit` etc.)
3. If you change the behavior of OnLoad and do not call base method, then you may break the page lifecycle of asp.net application. For instance, `Load` event will not be called.

Comment: then you may break the page lifecycle of asp.net application. -> How it will lead to break life cycle?

Comment: refer to your second question:)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the method `OnXxx` *raises* the event named `Xxx`. This is also the case in a `System.Web.UI.Control` like `Page`.

If you do:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // nothing here!
}
```

you change the behavior of `OnLoad` so that it now does nothing. Therefore, most probably, no-one will ever raise ("fire") the `Load` event. So its event handler is never run.

If instead you do:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // maybe add some code of your own here ...
  base.OnLoad(e);
  // ... or here
}
```

then the base call will make sure the method still raises the event.

You can only raise the event explicitly, i.e. invoke the underlying delegate, if you're in the class where the event was declared. So that's not a possibility for you. The base class where `Load` is defined does that like this:

```
// inside same class where 'Load' event is defined:

protected virtual void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
  // maybe they put some other code here ...

  var loadDelegate = Load;   // gets the current underlying delegate of the event
  if (loadDelegate != null)
    loadDelegate(this, e);

  // ... or here
}
```

But in most situation you shouldn't `override` any method at all. Just add to `Load` when you want some code to run when the `Load` event fires.

Comment: The last example (`var loadDelegate = Load`) is not legal. Just as properties encapsulate fields, events encapsulate delegates. You cannot access the underlying delegate via the publicly exposed event.

Comment: @MichaelLiu You're so right. I was confusing this situation with the case where we're in the same class where the `event` is declared. Will edit.